# What happens when app gets paused/stopped before receiving http response?

Tags: android

I have an app which sends a networking request and has a callback function associated with the response of the request.

What happens when app gets paused/stopped before receiving http response? Does the callback get executed in the background?

Comment: It depends how you handle your action, once app is stopped your context will become null. To prevent this make null check of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Apps* don't get paused/stopped, *activities* do. But when your activity is no longer the foreground activity, the OS can [freely kill](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem) your process at any time to free up memory. If the process gets killed, you won't get a callback anymore.

If this is just a regular HTTP request/response that returns within a second or so, I wouldn't worry about it.

If it's some long-running thing, look into using a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead.

Also be aware of the context, as @Arbaz Rizvi said in a comment: don't use your activity's context, but rather use `Context.getApplicationContext()` to get a process-wide context that is not tied to the activity.

Comment: Ok.. but what if the process doesnt get killed? Will the callback be executed then and would it be able to make UI changes?

Comment: The callback will get executed then. But whether it can make UI changes depends on whether your activity has been destroyed or not.